# Chrome-extension: any way to detect dom changes?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

Looking at this updated answer, [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener/11546242#11546242), it is still from 2012.

I'm wondering if there has been any changes since then to listen for dom changes in the google chrome extension.

Is it possible that there's a chrome API for detecting dom changes on the current page? For example, when you click a button, and the ajax loads some element on the current page?

If nothing specific for chrome, is there an updated way of listening for dom changes on the current page?

Comment: Nope, that's not how SO works. That question is still the mail question. And note, it's been updated with information about DOM Mutation Observers. One thing that can be added (maybe you can add it?) is a library, Mutation Summary.

Comment: Instead of posting a new question, add a comment to the old question asking if anything has changed.